# FFMPEG returns an error while trying to screencapture using AMD VCE

Tags: 17.10, ffmpeg, screencast, amdgpu, transcode

when I enter:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_vaapi -b:v 2M -maxrate 2M output.mp4
```

I get:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-netcdf
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
**input.mp4: No such file or directory**
```

I use ubuntu17.10/kernel 4.15 low latency with MESA 17.4 on a RX 580 8GB

Comment: The same the problem is that input.mp4 file it can not find it (And I dont know what it supposed to be)

Comment: same error ./input.mp4: No such file or directory,  What is the directory of the input file ? I dont know what that file is supposed to be... I want to record my screen and this is the command I found in the wiki that is supposed to do that.

Comment: Well thats the one on the wiki... Which one should I use to do what I would like to do?

Comment: I'm not really at home with these things, maybe try the one titled "*Capture the screen from X and encode with H.264 at reasonable constant-quality*" from [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI) (or something similar).

Comment: lol how could I miss that one? :P but its gives me a new error "[h264_vaapi @ 0x5592e29e4e80] B frames are not supported (0x1).
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height"  any ideas on how to turn off B frames (whatever those are :P )

Comment: I don't know, maybe you should [edit] the question and add the new command(s) you've tried and the full output. Somebody may be able to help then.